# how to create a sqlite3 table from a dictionary

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

db_file = 'data/raw/db.sqlite'
tables = {
    'Players': {
        'id': 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY',
        'fname': 'TEXT',
        'lname': 'TEXT',
        'dob': 'DATETIME',
        'age': 'INTEGER',
        'height': 'INTEGER', # inches
        'weight': 'INTEGER', # pounds
        'rank': 'INTEGER',
        'rhlh': 'INTEGER', # 0 - right, 1 - left
        'bh': 'INTEGER', # 0 - onehand, 1 - twohand
        'city': 'TEXT', # birth city
        'county': 'TEXT' #birth country
        }
}


conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
c = conn.cursor()

for table in tables.keys():
    for cols in tables[table].keys():
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ( \
                        {} {})".format(table, cols, tables[table][cols]))

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Is there a way to simply turn this `tables` nested dict object into a db table? The error I am getting `sqlite3.OperationalError: table Players already exists` which is obvious because I am calling `CREATE TABLE` more than once.

Does anyone have a quick trick in making a DB like so, using a nested dictionary which will eventually contain multiple tables?  Is this a terrible pracitce?  What should I do differently?

Thank you!

---

HOW I SOLVED:

Answer is below in comments.

Comment: You may want to overwrite the `db` file each time the script runs to prevent getting the already exists error from that as well -- while you're testing at least

Comment: `.execute("DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS Players")`

Comment: @furas what do you mean by this?

Comment: I would like to implement a one shot approach to creating this table.

Comment: you have problem because table exists - so remove it. If you use only `DROP TABLE` then you get error when table doesn't exist. With `IF EXISTS` this problem doesn't exist. In some databases may works even `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: it seems you can use [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS in SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/)

Comment: @furas issue is that, each time I will override and create a new table.. this will not give me all the column names as in the keys.

Comment: then use `"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` before `CREATE TABLE` or look for `ALTER TABLE` which can change existing table.

Comment: Solved in above edit.

Comment: You can put your solution as answer and mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
import sqlite3

db_file = 'data/raw/test3.sqlite'
initial_db = 'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
tables = {
    'Players': {
        'fname': 'TEXT',
        'lname': 'TEXT',
        'dob': 'DATETIME',
        'age': 'INTEGER',
        'height': 'INTEGER', # inches
        'weight': 'INTEGER', # pounds
        'rank': 'INTEGER',
        'rhlh': 'INTEGER', # 0 - right, 1 - left
        'bh': 'INTEGER', # 0 - onehand, 1 - twohand
        'city': 'TEXT', # birth city
        'country': 'TEXT' #birth country
        }
}


conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
c = conn.cursor()

for table in tables.keys():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ({})".format(table, initial_db))
    for k, v in tables[table].items():
        c.execute("ALTER TABLE {} \
                    ADD {} {}".format(table, k, v))

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, quick and probably dirty one, all in one query.

```
import sqlite3

db_file = 'data/raw/db.sqlite'
tables = {
    'Players': {
        'id': 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY',
        'fname': 'TEXT',
        'lname': 'TEXT',
        'dob': 'DATETIME',
        'age': 'INTEGER',
        'height': 'INTEGER', # inches
        'weight': 'INTEGER', # pounds
        'rank': 'INTEGER',
        'rhlh': 'INTEGER', # 0 - right, 1 - left
        'bh': 'INTEGER', # 0 - onehand, 1 - twohand
        'city': 'TEXT', # birth city
        'county': 'TEXT' #birth country
        }
}


conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
c = conn.cursor()

for table in tables.keys():
    fieldset = []
    for col, definition in tables[table].items():
        fieldset.append("'{0}' {1}".format(col, definition))

    if len(fieldset) > 0:
        query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ({1})".format(table, ", ".join(fieldset))

        c.execute(query)

c.close()
conn.close()
```