# convert string or text file to dictionary python (No JSON object could be decoded)

Tags: python, mysql, json, dictionary

**The Problem:**

I am trying to find a way to either convert a string, an object, or a text file into a dictionary so I can try to turn it into a sqlite database. (I apologize if I am going about this the wrong way. Feel free to recommend suggestions)

Currently I have a script which generates a list of all my mp4's metadata such as artists, song, album, year etc:

```
import os
import subprocess
from tinytag import TinyTag
import sqlite3
import json

tag = ''
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name)) 
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
```

if I export out the `tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)` using a combination of `text_file = open("sample.txt")` `tagfile = text_file.write(str(tag))` and `text_file.close()` I will get my results:

```
{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 332.06506666666667, "filesize": 550450310, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "27 Unknown", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive 2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 328.1945333333333, "filesize": 543487279, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "28 Unknown", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 372.80576666666667, "filesize": 617297262, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Blazed Up Melpomene", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 191.2911, "filesize": 315409615, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Bomb Factory - Exciter", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 388.75503333333336, "filesize": 645115333, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Bomb Factory - Exciter2", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 82.71596666666667, "filesize": 132912355, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "D.O.A", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 258.19126666666665, "filesize": 425217111, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Excelsior", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 342.8091333333333, "filesize": 567431045, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Grand Style", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 335.70203333333336, "filesize": 556799644, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Hitohira ~Reminiscent of Ketsui no Toko~", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 399.399, "filesize": 661114578, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Jintsuriki", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 304.97133333333335, "filesize": 504466425, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Natural High", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 327.8942333333333, "filesize": 542308702, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "Tehu Tehu", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}{"album": "Dead or Alive2", "albumartist": "Makoto Hosoi", "artist": "Makoto Hosoi", "audio_offset": null, "bitrate": 294651.393, "channels": 2, "comment": "Fighter", "composer": "Makoto Hosoi", "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 344.07706666666667, "filesize": 569536466, "genre": null, "samplerate": 48000, "title": "The Shooted 2", "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": "1999"}
# a lot more continued....
```

However if I try to load the text file as a json object so I can try and create a table with sqlite I get an error:

```
text_file = open("sample.txt")
line = text_file.read()
res = json.load(text_file)
```

Result:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I don't need to convert the data into a text file first but I need to find a way to turn `tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)` into a dictionary so I can try this: [how to create a sqlite3 table from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699090/how-to-create-a-sqlite3-table-from-a-dictionary)

```
# i am assuming this is what I will need but I need to make my data into a dictionary first
conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

for tablist in res.keys():
    fieldset = []
    for col, definition in res[tablist].items():
        fieldset.append("'{0}' {1}".format(col, definition))

    if len(fieldset) > 0:
        query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ({1})".format(tablist, ", ".join(fieldset))

        c.execute(query)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

If anyone has any suggestions or different methods to try out, let me know.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: You are not constructing valid JSON. You write multiple JSON on the same line without any separator. This is "almost" `ndjson` where every line is valid JSON, but they have to be on separate lines and still you will need to process line bi line afterwards. If you want a valid JSON - yoi need to make list of dicts that will be transformed into array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error with the generated json objects. The json you posted is not a valid json object, thats why you couldn't parse it out.

For a valid json object you should :

1. Start your json file with `[` at the beginning
2. Make sure there is a `,` in between each object
3. End your json file with `]`

Also thought I might share a more efficient way of opening files with python.

```py
import json

with open('sample.json', 'r') as sample:
    json.load(sample)
```

If we open the file this way we can avoid forgetting to close the file after we read/write it. After it runs the code inside it it will close the file for you.

Comment: In that case, I probably going to find a different way of doing this. Maybe I can convert `tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)` into a dict? I will mark this as the answer since I am pretty sure I will need to look for a different method. Thanks again!

Comment: @JatonJameerJustice You may be able to just add those characters after each object and start and end the file with `[` and `]` by simply writing the characters. Though you might want to find a better more reliable way in this case.

Comment: There are over 6000 songs. I was only exporting to a text file to try to find a way to put this into sqlite so I can try search queries against the data. There is no way I can go into that text file and edit it. I will have to try a different method. Good ideas though!

Comment: @JatonJameerJustice I mean append them programmatically into the file. Before you start parsing the metadata you add `[` and after each object you add `,` and after you are done collecting each item you add `]` before you close the file

Comment: I don't know how that is possible. `[` and `]` makes sense but I don't know how to add `,` inbetween each result. `tag` give me the list of all of the results at the same time. I don't know how to break that up. I would assume `tag_str = str("{" + tag + "]")` but I don't know where `,` is suppose to go. I think I will approach this from trying to convert `tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)` into a dict instead as I don't see how this will work using a text file.